# how can fix localhost url in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

every time when I  run my web app in visual studio 2017 this
"**(S(zwvqridsdqfqioztfkngivah))**" alway come with
URL how to fix it..?

example-http://localhost:64537/(S(zwvqridsdqfqioztfkngivah))/About

Comment: This wouldn't appear if you hadn't *explicitly* requested it. That's the session ID for cookiless sessions. The default behaviour is to use cookies. You have to explicitly configure cookieless sessions in web.config

Answer (score 3):

The string you are looking at is the session ID. 
asp.net can do [cookieless sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) by putting the session ID in the URL.

You can turn it off by setting sessionState to `<sessionState cookieless="false" />` in your web.config

(keep in mind this will change the behavior back to putting the session ID in a cookie on the browser, but also that cookieless sessions are an easy attack vector, so you should probably do this anyway.)

Comment: More information about cookieless sessions for example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `(S...)` part is the session state identifier. I think you have enabled [cookieless sessions in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).

In order to switch to cookie-based sessions, change your web.config to this:

```
<sessionState
   mode="InProc"
   cookieless="UseCookies"
   />
```